# Sql - how to calculate 2 separate sub queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I do not have the best understanding of SQL, doing my best to learn. I have built two separate queries, and I am looking to take the result from query 1 and divide it by query 2.

Query 1 (Result is 114)

```
select count(*) as Numerator

from (

SELECT   *,  
           DATEDIFF(SECOND, xx, yy) AS SecondDiff, 
           DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS DayDiff

FROM database1.dbo.tbl1

WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and DATEDIFF(DAY, xx,yy) <= 15

)t1
```

Query 2 (result is 131)

```
select count(*) as Denominator

from(

SELECT   *,  
           DATEDIFF(SECOND, xx, yy) AS SecondDiff, 
           DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS DayDiff

FROM database1.dbo.tbl1

WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
       and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))


)t2
```

Now how do I take the results from query 1 and divide it by query 2 and have the end result be (Column name: Total_X)? I have tried to use union, cross join, cross apply but I cannot seem to get a working query!

Every tip and advice is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CROSS JOIN BETWEEN the two query eg:

```
  select TT1.Numerator/ TT2.Denominator
  from (
    select count(*) as Numerator

  from (

  SELECT   *,  
             DATEDIFF(SECOND, xx, yy) AS SecondDiff, 
             DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS DayDiff

  FROM database1.dbo.tbl1

  WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
         and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
         and DATEDIFF(DAY, xx,yy) <= 15

  )t1) TT1 
  CROSS JOIN ( 

  select count(*) as Denominator

  from(

  SELECT   *,  
             DATEDIFF(SECOND, xx, yy) AS SecondDiff, 
             DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS DayDiff

  FROM database1.dbo.tbl1

  WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
         and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))


  )t2 ) TT2
```

could be related  to integer division try  a simple cast

```
select cast(TT1.Numerator AS DECIMAL(9,2))/CAST( TT2.Denominator AS DECIMAL(9.2))
  from (
    select count(*) as Numerator

  from (

  SELECT   *,  
             DATEDIFF(SECOND, xx, yy) AS SecondDiff, 
             DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS DayDiff

  FROM database1.dbo.tbl1

  WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
         and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
         and DATEDIFF(DAY, xx,yy) <= 15

  )t1) TT1 
  CROSS JOIN ( 

  select count(*) as Denominator

  from(

  SELECT   *,  
             DATEDIFF(SECOND, xx, yy) AS SecondDiff, 
             DATEDIFF(DAY, xx, yy) AS DayDiff

  FROM database1.dbo.tbl1

  WHERE  month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))
         and year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp))


  )t2 ) TT2
```

Comment: I am getting the result as 0 for some reason but the query works, thanks for the help. Any clue what the value would return as 0

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, xx,yy) <= 15 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM database1.dbo.tbl1
WHERE month(datecompleted) = month(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp)) AND
      year(datecompleted) = year(dateadd(month,-1,current_timestamp));
```

You can also simplify the `WHERE` clause to:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, xx,yy) <= 15 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM database1.dbo.tbl1
WHERE datecompleted < DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(current_timestamp), CONVERT(DATE, datecompleted)) AND
      datecompleted >= DATEADD(month, 1, DATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(current_timestamp), CONVERT(DATE, datecompleted))) AND
```

This version can make use of an index on `datecompleted`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can convert rows to column and divide it.
   Assuming your first query is
   select 1 value, 'nm' type from dual;
   second query is
   select 2 value, 'dm' type from dual

Convert rwos to column and divide

> select sum(decode(type,'nm',value)) numerator,
>   sum(decode(type,'dm',value)) denominator ,
>   sum(decode(type,'nm',value))/sum(decode(type,'dm',value))
>   divided_value   from (select 1 value, 'nm' type from dual   union
>   select 2 value, 'dm' type from dual)   group by 1,2

or directly

```
  select 1/(select 2 from dual) from dual;
```

Comment: Your answer looks like Oracle.  The question does not.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with computed table expressions.

```
with numerator
as (
select count(*) n1
from someTable
) 
, denominator as
(select count(*) n2
from anotherTable)

select n1 / n2
from numerator, denominator
where n2 > 0
```

Note that

```
from numerator, denominator
```

is effectively a cross join, as suggested by @scaisEdge

Also note that your actual queries look to be more complicated than necessary.